# Multi user HTML5 Canvas sketching with JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Anyone knows a good tutorial/js plugin to create a multi user html5 sketch web application?
Would be nice to have cross browser compatibility, preferably without any tools that need to be installed server side.

If the latter is not possible, I would also be happy if the application just saves the user x's sketch so that next time someone loads the app, it would show user x's sketch on startup.

Thanks for your advise.

PS. I have looked at [Mr. Doob's](http://mrdoob.com/projects/multiuserpad/), he uses node.js, unfortunately my hosting does not support this just yet. Hence I am asking for a solution that need no server side installation. Also the [multi user drawing pad by Union Platform](http://www.unionplatform.com/?page_id=2762) seems to fit the bill, but unfortunately it also requires something to be installed.

Comment: Anything with multiple users will need something on the back end to tie them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Mr. Doob's implementation uses Node.js is because node is great at this kind of things. Since this is going to involve delivering realtime changes to different users, your best bet is to use Comet/Ajax-Push/Longpolling. And if you want to support multi-window usage(multiple browser tabs having your sketchpad), you would need to implement http connection pooling to get around the connection limits set by browsers as per http standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to shift to a new web host for this application you can use Heroku. Heroku is free and supports Node.js.

I created a multi-user Agile project management whiteboard using WebSockets and Node.js and found a 624% increase in requests per second vs using HTTP. I use MongoDB on the back end which allows you to store data as serialized JSON... this means you can send JSON between client <-> Server <-> Database with no parsing (very fast).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use websockets which are fairly new anyways, Then I would suggest using ajax polling of some sort.  Basically use ajax calls based on a delay.

This wikipedia article shows some of the various options you should do further reading into.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29